# Every cut in R+ ist a dedekind cut?

Tags: complex-analysis, dedekind-domain

I have hard time proving obvious theories. For my Analysis class they asked me to proof that ever cut in R+ is a dedekind cut.
I know these are the defintions:
A Dedekind cut is a pair (A, B), where A and B are both subsets of rationals.
This pair has to satisfy the following properties.

- A is nonempty.
- B is nonempty.
- If a ∈ A and c < a then c ∈ A.
- If b ∈ B and c > b then c ∈ B.
- If b not∈ B and a < b, then a ∈ A.
- If a not∈ A and b > a, then b ∈ B.
- For each a ∈ A there is some b > a so that b ∈ A.
- For each b ∈ B there is some a < b so that a ∈ B.

But how can I actually proof that?

Comment: and what is a (potentially non-Dedekind) cut?

Comment: What's the definition of a cut that is *not* a Dedekind cut?

Comment: Also, it seems strange to me that $(\Bbb Q,\Bbb Q)$ is - according yo your definition - a Dedekind cut

Comment: That's way a long, cumbersome definition of Dedekind cut, imho, and besides the repetition of some equivalent conditions, the very last one is, as far as I know, specifically wrong, as "the upper" set in the partition defining the D. cut isn't required to fulfill that it doesn't have a minimal element. Now, A really is required not have a maximal element...